# Are regex check constraints possible in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex, check-constraints

I am trying to find a way to validate data in my columns using regex CHECK constraints but have so far only come across the `LIKE` keyword that has an extremely limited subset of regex syntax. I'd like to know if there is a way to use regex in check constraints?

I am using SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Comment: So far, I've only found one DBE that supports posix regex constraints and it is Oracle (Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157662/is-there-a-database-engine-that-allows-for-queriable-field-constraint-specified). MS SQL and DB2 look like they have their own wildcard variant, which is unfortunate as you loose consistency of constraints between layers :(

Comment: Relevant QA on the DBA site... https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/266438/3690

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can create a CLR scalar UDF which can use the .Net framework RegEx classes, and then call that from your check constraint.

In fact, [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) discusses this scenario (search for "Check Constraint", then move backwards through the article to find implementation details).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the thread here but check out my article about how to do this:

http://xmlsqlninja.blogspot.com/2013/09/mdqregex-clr-functions-part-3-regex.html