# Is There A Database Engine that Allows for Queriable Field Constraint Specified by RegEx?

Tags: sql-server, regex, database, oracle, database-engine

I'm looking for a database engine that can handle data constraints specified via RegEx. So in addition to the datatype, I want to be able to control the format of the data. E.g. a `varchar(255)` field could be further restrained to be like `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]`.

I need the RegEx to be able to be queried too, so I can share those constraints throughout the n-tier system to enforce on several levels. E.g. MySQL allows for querying of `information_schema` to get meta data, and other database engines have similar ways.

I did a post yesterday ([MySQL Queriable Field Constraint by RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142303/mysql-queriable-field-constraint-by-regex)), referencing things I read, but doesn't look promising with MySQL, so I'm opening this up to any db engine, although I would prefer MS SQL, Oracle, DB2 or MySQL, as it'll be easier to sell the business on.

Is there a database engine out there that allows for these regex restrictions? If so, which one is it and how do the constraints get set and queried?

Comment: Have you tried even a little bit of research? Oracle has RegEx, sql server has a limited wildcard pattern. Either of those would work for your simple example.

Comment: References for Sean's comments... MS SQL only has limited regex support (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) and oracle's is more extensive (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_regexp.htm)

Comment: Still looking into DB2... So far it looks like DB2 does a wild card like MS SQL, looking to see if they support something more in depth (reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154453/how-to-write-a-query-to-ensure-email-contains)

Comment: PostgreSQL has strong regexp support including check constraints and indexing

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle you can specify custom [constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm), in which you can use functions that evaluate [regexp](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm); for example:

```
SQL> create table test_pattern ( txt varchar2(1000))
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> alter table test_pattern add constraint check_pattern check (regexp_instr(txt, '^START') != 0)
  2  /

Table altered.

SQL> insert into test_pattern values ('START a d f  g ')
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test_pattern values ('_START a d f  g ')
  2  /
insert into test_pattern values ('_START a d f  g ')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SIUINTEGRA.CHECK_PATTERN) violated
```

You can get informations on constraints you set with something like:

```
select *
from dba_constraints       
where table_name = 'TEST_PATTERN'
```

Comment: What is the output of your constraints query? Also is there a particular version I need to use to get this functionality?

Comment: It gives all the informations about constraints (table, schema, if they are deferred, deferrable, the check condition, ...). It works on Oracle 10g and above; previous versions do not support regexp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a wildcard example in sql server for this.

```
create table #Something
(
    SomeValue varchar(255)
    , constraint MyCheck CHECK (SomeValue like '[a-z][a-z][0-9]%')
)

insert #Something
select 'ab3adoofnod'
--(1 row(s) affected)

insert #Something
select 'a3b3adoofnod'

Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "MyCheck". The conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "dbo.#Something__________________________________________________________________________________________________________0000000000DD", column 'SomeValue'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

If you want to use some t-sql to view the definitions of your check constraints you can use the sys.check_constraints catalog view.

Here is an example to view ALL the check constraints for the table above. The definition columns will provide the wildcard searching as defined in the constraint.

```
select * 
from tempdb.sys.check_constraints
where parent_object_id = object_id('tempdb..#Something')
```

Comment: How do you query the regex in the check?

Comment: Not sure I follow your question. The check constraint says the value must have 2 characters followed by a number.

Comment: Part of the question is how to query the meta data of the constraint. In MySQL you can query the `information_schema` table to get meta data of the column. How do you query the MS SQL DBE to get the meta data of `[a-z][a-z][0-9]%` of this column/field?

Comment: You really should try to look things up. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187388.aspx

Comment: The intent was to help you write a complete answer, so people would vote for your answer. Having partial answers then googling is a waste for others with similar questions. Furthermore, links with MS tend to get outdated with time too, so having a complete history/answer in stack overflow is one of the benefits of stack overflow... if you update your answer to be complete, I'll give you an up vote :)

Comment: LOL. You didn't ask about being to view the check constraint. Not something many people do all that frequently. Sorry if I came across as snarky. :D

Comment: in tsql you can use XML Schema with a pattern constraint containing the regex and add a check constraint so inserts/updates are validated or create your own CLR function, take a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266438/how-can-i-enforce-that-values-in-a-table-column-match-the-regular-expression-a